# Nunit test fails when not in debug mode

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

when I run the TEST in debug mode it works, otherwise it fails.

I am using `Moq`.

When the following line is added everything works fine.

`_repositoryMock.Setup(m => m.GetSingleBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Configuration, bool>>>())).Returns((Configuration)null);`

Without the line above it works only in DEBUG mode.

```
[Test]
public void ChangeServiceTier() {
 //Arrange
 const int configurationId = 6;
 const int serviceTierId = 12;

 //Act
 var result = _configurationService.ChangeServiceTier(configurationId, serviceTierId);

 //Assert
 result.Should().BeNull();

}
```

Method

```
 public ConfigurationDto ChangeServiceTier(int id, int serviceTierId) {
  var cfg = _repository.GetSingleBy < Configuration > (s => s.Id == id);

  if (cfg == null) {
   return null;
  }
  return _mapper.Map < ConfigurationDto > (cfg);
 }
```

TEST Fail rason:
`Message: Expected result to be <null>, but found ConfigurationDto...`

For some reason, `cfg` is null only in debug MODE.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try to debug and step into the `_repository`?

Comment: I notice that `_repositoryMock` has a leading underscore, implying that you've made it a class member.  Is it possible that in debug mode the tests are simply running in a different order to release mode, and you're leaving something lying around in the test that is now executing first?

Comment: @ZoranHorvat repository is mocked like this ` _repositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository>();`

Comment: @Colin whereabouts are you performing that initialisation?

Comment: @LordWilmore in the constructor. Without any decorator.

Comment: Don't you have other tests in that fixture that actually use the same parameters calling `ChangeServiceTier` method? I assume one of them will be setting up return result and affecting that test. Try changing the parameters. If that's not the case then as you mentioned - setting up your mock to return null will be just fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks, @LordWilmore I have removed constructor and added [SetUp] method instead. It works now.

Comment: It is unusual to have a constructor in a test class, and using SetUp as you suggested is the correct way.  The difference will be that when you had a constructor, that constructor was called once, so if you didn't explicitly tidy up after each test then the affects of any previous test will be left lying around.  The [SetUp] method is called before every [Test] method, so initialising in here means that you are creating a new instance each time.  I would still suggest creating the item within each test if required, rather than as a class member, for this exact reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @LordWilmore

It is unusual to have a constructor in a test class, and using SetUp as you suggested is the correct way. The difference will be that when you had a constructor, that constructor was called once, so if you didn't explicitly tidy up after each test then the affects of any previous test will be left lying around. The [SetUp] method is called before every [Test] method, so initialising in here means that you are creating a new instance each time. I would still suggest creating the item within each test if required, rather than as a class member, for this exact reason. – LordWilmore

Comment: I'd suggest refining this answer a bit. NUnit does __not__ guarantee your constructor will only be called once, although that's what usually happens. If you want the values set for every test, use SetUp or OneTimeSetUp. Since these are just ints it probably makes no difference, but it's a good habit to get into. As stated, if the values are for one test, put them in the test.